# 16gb memory stick pro hg duo shows 126gb

Tags: memorystick

My psp's memory stick got corrupted. I cannot reformat via psp nor windows 10 pc. I have tried to delete volume, there was no choice. Even found a solution in here and tried to use bootice. I cannot reformat my memory stick.
I am open any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind loosing all data, as you are using windows, you can use the DISKPART cli because the msc gui does not cover all functions you have with DISKPART. Just use the HELP function in DISKPART, it's easy. comment where you're stuck

Comment: When I tried this method, stuck here:
-cmd
-diskpart
-list disk
-select disk 1
-clear (now I am trying clear all but it seems last forever)
-create partition primary
Here I am stuck. It throws ;
No usable free extent could be found. It may be that there is insufficient
free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. Specify
different size and offset values or don't specify either to create the....etc

Comment: Sorry I am newbie here. When I hit enter button it sends my comment but I am trying to add a new line. How can it be possible? My stick is 16gb but computer shows it's 126gb?

Comment: CLEAR is no DISKPART command. you mean CLEAN ?

Comment: try it with LIST DISK, SELECT DISK X, SELECT PART 1, DELETE PART, repeat with reimaining

Comment: if you have any linux distro (live) available, dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX would do it in a second.

Comment: you also can try gparted live iso, and use unetbootin to write it on a usb stick

Comment: or the HP USB FORMAT TOOL: https://www.heise.de/download/product/hp-usb-disk-storage-format-tool-97463

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try with my ubuntu device then.
Yes I mean CLEAN. Tried to DELETE PART also does not work.
How can I do it with my ubuntu?
Thanks for the help I will try and inform if it works or not.

Comment: with ubuntu just use the gparted package, should be included in the live system